# Python - Unicode De/Encode

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, python-unicode

How can I pass all the content from making a db-input(s1), loading it from there (s2) and pass it correctly back-formated to the file?

```
import time,os,sys,base64
s = "Hello World!\r\nHeyho"
#with s1 i make an input to the database; with s2 I select it -> works most time
s1 = base64.b64encode(s.encode("UTF-8")).decode("UTF-8") #print("Base64 Encoded:", s1)
s2 = base64.b64decode(s1.encode("UTF-8")).decode("UTF-8") #print(s2)

#example that I try to save it in a file:
s3 = "PGhlYWQ+CiAgICA8dGl0bGU+4pa3IEltbW9iaWxpZW4gLSBIw6R1c2VyIC0gV29obnVuZ2VuIC0gZmluZGVuIGJlaSBpbW1vd2VsdC5kZTwvdGl0bGU+"
with open("C:\\Users\\001\\Downloads\\Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write("Ausgabe: %s" % base64.b64decode(s3.encode("UTF-8")).decode("UTF-8")) #with .encode('ascii', 'ignore') i whould delete the signs
```

Log:

```
C:\Users\001\Downloads>python trythis.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trythis.py", line 11, in <module>
    text_file.write("Ausgabe: %s" % base64.b64decode(s3.encode("UTF-8")).decode("UTF-8")) #with .encode('ascii', 'ignore') i whould delelte signs
  File "C:\Users\001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25b7' in position 28: character maps to <undefined>
```

EDIT: I am working on windows.

```
C:\Users\001\Downloads>python -V
Python 3.5.2
```

Comment: File "C:\Users\001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\cp1252.py" would seem to indicate that as part of the write process its trying to take your string and encode it as cp1252 (windows ascii).  What exactly are you trying to do since I see a lot of uncesscary encode/decode from UTF-8.  Python 3 already handles most of that in the background for you as strings are unicode by default.

Comment: @WombatPM, there is no such thing as "Windows ASCII". ASCII and Windows-1252 are two different character encodings. But you're right about the rest. I assume that `s1` and `s2` are just in the code to demonstrate the failed attempts to decode the data properly. Only `s3` seems relevant. The UTF-8 decoding is necessary because the Base64-encoded data is actually part of a UTF-8 encoded HTML page. And `base64.b64decode()` returns a `bytes` object. So in this case it is necessary.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. windows-1252 corresponds to codepage 1252  which consists of the ascii character set + western european extended ascii characters.  It predates unicode and is essentially the default in a lot of windows based tools and systems sold in the united states which tend to hide the complexity from end users. For a fun time read https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/table-iso8859-1-vs-windows-1252.html to see how we have cp-1252, iso-8859-1, iso-8859-15, utf-8, utf-16 and html entities being similar yet different in ways that you don't uncover until much much later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you open the file in text mode, but don't specify the encoding. In that case the system default encoding is used, which may be different on any system.

**Solution:** specify the `encoding` argument to [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

As a side-note: why do you `.decode('UTF-8')`? It *does* work, but since the data is Base64-encoded, I think ASCII decoding would make more sense. Besides, you should only encode/decode at the I/O boundaries (so in this case when writing to file), although you may have done it for testing/demonstration purposes only in this case.

**Update:**

Apparently your Base64-encoded data is also UTF-8 encoded (first UTF-8, then Base64), so that's why you need to first Base64-decode then UTF-8-decode it.

The following is a portable, working example:

```py
import base64

b64_encoded_text = 'PGhlYWQ+CiAgICA8dGl0bGU+4pa3IEltbW9iaWxpZW4gLSBIw6R1c2VyIC0gV29obnVuZ2VuIC0gZmluZGVuIGJlaSBpbW1vd2VsdC5kZTwvdGl0bGU+'
decoded_text = base64.b64decode(b64_encoded_text).decode('utf-8')

with open('Output.txt', 'wt', encoding='utf-8') as text_file:
    text_file.write('Ausgabe: %s' % decoded_text)
```

Although it's even easier to just write the raw binary (UTF-8 encoded) data to the file:

```py
import base64

b64_encoded_text = 'PGhlYWQ+CiAgICA8dGl0bGU+4pa3IEltbW9iaWxpZW4gLSBIw6R1c2VyIC0gV29obnVuZ2VuIC0gZmluZGVuIGJlaSBpbW1vd2VsdC5kZTwvdGl0bGU+'

with open('Output.txt', 'wb') as file:
    # file.write(b'Ausgabe: ')  # uncomment if really needed
    file.write(base64.b64decode(b64_encoded_text))
```

Answer (score 0):

404pio seems to be correct. Your code runs fine with Python 3 in my system. What might be happening is that Windows is taking Python 2 as the default when you run `python trythis.py`

You will find your Python 3 installation at

> C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\

directory, it should have a folder by the name Python37-32 or similar. Either use the Python 3 binary inside `bin` directory of that folder (by specifying the full path in the command prompt

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\bin\python trythis.py
```

or add that folder to your PATH environment variable (and remove python 2 path from it).

Link for how to modify PATH variable https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: The OP already demonstrated that she's using Python 3.5.2 and the traceback confirms that. I'm also missing an explanation why Python 2 would cause this specific error. Did you try to run it using Python 2? The reason that the code runs fine at your system is probably that your system has a different text encoding. The OP is using Windows-1252. Maybe you're running Linux (which likely uses UTF-8), or live in a different country with a different system encoding.